# Cannot install octave on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: java, 14.10, octave

I try to install `octave` on `ubuntu 14.10` by

```
$ sudo apt-get install octave
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 octave : Depends: default-jre-headless but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I whent down the rabbit hole by trying to install `default-jre-headless`, etc. till i came to `tzdata-java` which produced the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tzdata-java : Depends: tzdata (= 2014i-0ubuntu0.14.10) but 2015a-0ubuntu0.14.10 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

According to [Ubuntu updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/utopic/main/proposed/tzdata-java) this is not part of the distro anymore. How do I install `octave` then?

Edit:

Some additional info:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy tzdata-java

tzdata-java:
Installed: (none)
 Candidate: 2014i-0ubuntu0.14.10
 Version table:
    2014i-0ubuntu0.14.10 0
       500 http://mirror.math.ucdavis.edu/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages
       500 http://mirror.math.ucdavis.edu/ubuntu/ utopic-security/main amd64 Packages
    2014h-2 0
       500 http://mirror.math.ucdavis.edu/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
```

According to [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/amd64/tzdata-java/2015b-0ubuntu0.14.10) however there should be a never version of this. How do I update the definitions then (if this is the problem)? I already did `sudo apt-get upgrade/update/dist-upgrade`

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get install default-jre-headless`

Comment: Octave is in universe - http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=octave you may need to enable the universe repository

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I already did `update/upgrade/dist-upgrade`, `-f` didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report then , should be easy to fix the dependencies

Comment: Well, I don't know considering that I didn't find anybody else with the same issue, I think the problem is on my end. I just don't see it yet...

Comment: It looks like a problem with tzdata-java depending on tzdata . Unless you manually installed tzdata, and assuming your system is up to date, you did nothing wrong.

Comment: Okey,I'll try that then. Where would you file it, with ubuntu or octave?

Comment: looks like tzdata-java , but include the same information you posted here in the bug report and it will be triaged

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22553/discussion-between-magu-and-bodhi-zazen).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was an old version of tzdata-java

Installing the never version with `sudo apt-get install tzdata-java=2015b-0ubuntu0.14.10` actually did the trick.